# Litecoin transaction never reached my adress

Tags: transactions, litecoin

Hi I did a Litecoin transaction from Mercado Bitcoin to Bitstamp and it never reached the destination.

The platform mercado bitcoin says my transaction was completed and it doesn't and when I click on the transaction code it the website blockcypher and Blockchai.info, both say the transaction wasn't found. In the meantime I have no more litecoins in mercado bitcoin and no litecoins appear on Bitstamp.

Here is the transaction code: 68b9ba2f30afc3eca80ba36df298f5e1d91f9aa5b282306233d6d767ca1acddf

Did I loose my litecoins?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If they can't give you a transaction ID that you can find in a block explorer, then there is no evidence to support their claim that they completed the transaction.